# Haar Cascade training with multiple positive images

Tags: linux, opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I'm trying to train my own haar cascade to detect guns. I have downloaded close to 2000 negative images and I want to detect many sorts of guns. So, haar cascade needs to be trained with many positive gun images I guess. How can it be done?

BTW, I'm working on Linux / Ubuntu environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I propose to train for each gun a classifier :)

Comment: I'm a newbie in haar cascade creation, trying to find the best way to create it. If your advice is the straight way of doing it, I would try that ;) By saying guns, I was not thinking about separating the types of guns. I need cascade to sense it like  "Yes, this is a gun !"

Comment: you can use Cascade Trainer GUI - Amin for windows. i am using ubuntu too. and  i have installed wine and i am using cascade trainer with it.

Answer (score 1):

For training haar cascades for detecting custom objects you can use the opencv library. On debian/ubuntu linux or its derivatives this can be installed by running the below command as the root user:

```
# apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Once that is successful, I found the code and steps at [this site](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) very useful to learn about training haar cascades. The author has demonstrated with an example.

There is also an associated git repository [here](https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training). The Readme.md presents the set of steps concisely. Step #1 is for installing opencv and may be ignored.

The key to successful training is to get a sufficient number of positive and negative images.

Comment: To understand the process in greater detail I found this  [tutorial](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) by Naotoshi Seo and the last 5-6 videos in [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdttJXlLtAJxJetJcqmqlQq) to be extremely useful.